# Группировка функций Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При попытке указать в инспекторе какую-то функцию скрипта как **UnityEvent** (например при срабатывании **onClick** у кнопки можно указать вызов функций от скриптов на различных объектах/компонентах) можно выбрать из списка функций для этого скрипта. Но, если например в скрипте много публичных функций, можно ли как-то их сгруппировать в различные подгруппы в этом скрипте? В Unity вроде были подобные **атрибуты** для контекстного меню, но они вроде в основном для статических функций вне сцены.

*(Картинка с абстрактным примером)*
[image: Картинка с абстрактным примером большого количества функций]

Comment: На самом деле большое количество публичных методов говорит о неправильной архитектуре класса)) Понимаю, что вопрос про группировку в любом случае имеет смысл быть, но в целом, в классе при хорошем раскладе должно быть десяток публичных методов. Иначе это какой-то божественный компонент, а, следовательно, неправильная разработка

Comment: Можно, написать еще одну функцию, которая вызывает несколько соседей сразу. :)